# How to resize ggplot graph in r notebook

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, r-markdown, rnotebook

I want to resize ggplot graph in Rnotebook.

[image]

It's too big it doesn't show anything like above. When I export it and increase the size about 4 times bigger, then it shows the details.

I've attempted the followings:
set_plot_options
fig.height, fig.width

to resize the graph but it didn't apply.

Please share if you have knowledge of how to resize plots.

Comment: Setting the `fig.height` and `fig.width` chunk options seems to work fine for me...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your chunk should start with something like:

`{r, fig.width = 12, fig.height = 12}`

Comment: The numbers are [in inches..](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/213106048/comments/115003165368)